# Doing multiple html element animations

Tags: javascript, html

I want to animate different sections of a web page only when they are scrolled into view using vanilla javascript. This is what my code looks like right now

```
<script>
    let target = document.querySelector("#who-we-are");
    let service = document.querySelector("#what-we-do");

    function animateAboutUs() {
        if (target.scrollIntoView) {
            document.querySelector("#who").classList.add("fadeIn");
        }
    }

    function animateServiceList() {
        if (service.scrollIntoView) {
            document.querySelector("#service").classList.add("fadeIn");
        }
    }

    window.onscroll = function() {
        animateAboutUs();
        animateServiceList();
    };
</script>
```

The problem with doing it like this is that once a user starts to scroll down the page the `service` section gets animated even when its yet to come into view.

What is the proper way to do animation only when the section is scrolled into view for multiple sections?

Comment: The problem is that `scrollIntoView` is a function not a boolean indicating that the element is inside the viewport. You'll have to check the scroll position and the element's position to determine if it is inside the viewport.

Comment: @Titus so is it ok to call both `animateAboutUs` and `animateServiceList` inside `window.scroll` the way I am doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modern solution would be to use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) instead of listening to the scroll event.

First you define the observer:

```
var options = {
  root: document.querySelector('#scrollArea'),
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.1
}
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Threshold of .1 means that the `callback()` function gets called as soon as 10% (or more) are visible. Adjust this as you see fit obviously.
If you omit the root option the browser viewport is used.

Then you observe items:

```
var target = document.querySelector('.scrollItems');
observer.observe(target);
```

Now, whenever the target meets a threshold specified for the IntersectionObserver, the callback is invoked.

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // this loops through each element that is visible, add your classes here
    entry.addClass('fadeIn');
  });
}
```

Note: If you also need to support older browsers, [there is a polyfill available.](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill)

Comment: Sounds like a good way to go. Let me read up some more on it then try to implement it since its not a live project and I am learning. I will make it as correct answer once i have a grasp

Comment: IntersectionObserver is so cool, love it. Thanks for introducing me to this API.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var $animation_elements = $('.animation-element');
var $window = $(window);
function check_if_in_view() {
var window_height = $window.height();
var window_top_position = $window.scrollTop();
var window_bottom_position = (window_top_position + window_height);

$.each($animation_elements, function() {
var $element = $(this);
var element_height = $element.outerHeight();
var element_top_position = $element.offset().top;
var element_bottom_position = (element_top_position + element_height );

//check to see if this current container is within viewport
if ((element_bottom_position >= window_top_position) &&
  (element_top_position <= window_bottom_position)) {
  $element.addClass('in-view');
} else {
  $element.removeClass('in-view');
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other generic solution using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) and [eventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

See the comments on the example below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.section').forEach(section => {
  const rect = section.getBoundingClientRect(); // get position of section
  if(rect.top < document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight){ // check initial if a section is in view
    section.classList.add('fadeIn');
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", addClass(section, rect)); // add eventlistener
  }
});

function addClass(element, rect) {
  const offset = 100; // set an offset to the needed scrollposition (in px)
  let handler = () => {
    if(rect.top < document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight - offset){ // check if scrollposition is reached
      element.classList.add('fadeIn');
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handler); // remove eventlistener
      console.log(`reached section ${element.id}`);
    }
  };
  return handler;
}
```

```css
.section {
  height: 100vh;
  color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.section.fadeIn {
  color: #000 !important;
}

#one { background-color: yellow }
#two { background-color: green }
#three { background-color: orange }
#four { background-color: lightblue }
#five { background-color: grey }
```

```html
<div class="section" id="one">Faded In!</div>
<div class="section" id="two">Faded In!</div>
<div class="section" id="three">Faded In!</div>
<div class="section" id="four">Faded In!</div>
<div class="section" id="five">Faded In!</div>
```